# Como puedo hacer VALIDACIONES de 3 cadenas de STRINGS en Java Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, string, validación

Tengo dos clases Instrumento (contiene nombres de instrumentos) y Musico (contiene Instrumento, nombredelmusico y posicion)
La validacion que tengo que relaizar es: **Si el nombre de musico no corresponde con su instrumento y con su posicion imprimir error.**
Aparte debo validar que esten todos los integrantes.

Para comparar solo dos Strings en otro ejercicio he usado lo siguiente:
*String cadena1 = new String("Hola");
String cadena2 = new String("Hola");
if (cadena1.equals(cadena2))
{
   ...
}*

hasta ahi todo bien, pero no se como como meter el tercer strings. Pense en usar un else pero no se como guardar la primer comparacin como una sola cadena.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Esta es una comunidad de ayuda mutua en la que hay un requisito esencial: quien pregunta debe ser el primero en mostrar el interés por resolver su problema. Tal y como está planteada tu pregunta actualmente se puede interpretar como que estás diciendo *hagan esto por mi*. No es el objetivo de este sitio, sino ayudarte a aprender/resolver tu problema partiendo desde un error concreto. Por tanto, ¿qué has investigado/intentado?  ¿Qué código has implementado? ¿Qué errores estás teniendo? Sin esos indicadores tu pregunta podría ser cerrada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recuerda que el método `equals()` retorna un boolean (es decir, con valores `true`  o `false`). Puedes construir una expresión usando [operadores boolean](https://es.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programaci%C3%B3n_en_Java/Operadores_booleanos) como && (and) y || (or)

```
if ( uno.equals(dos) && dos.equals(tres) ) {
   :
}
```

Comment: Te lo agradesco hermano.